# How to return an Observable sequence with optional value

Tags: rx-swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNymi.png)

```
class Api{
    
    static let shared = Api()
    private let provider = MoyaProvider<MultiTarget>(plugins:[NetworkLoggerPlugin(),CryptoPlugin()])
    
    public func send<T : Codable>(_ target : TargetType, type : T.Type) -> Observable<T?> {
        let mTarget = MultiTarget(target)
        return provider.rx.request(mTarget)
            .asObservable()
            .filterSuccessfulStatusCodes()
            .map { result in
                print(String(data: result.data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "111")
                
                let responseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel<T>.self, from: result.data)
                if(responseModel.code != 0) { // business error
                    let msg = (responseModel.msgCode != nil) ? Localized(key: "\(responseModel.msgCode!)") : responseModel.msg
                    UIApplication.shared.currentKeyWindow()?.showHUD(msg)
                    return nil
                }
                if(responseModel.data == nil){
                    responseModel.data = T.Type()
                }
                return responseModel.data
            }
            .catchAndReturn(T.self as? T)
    }
}
```

the problem is sometimes the server side will return nil data EVEN there is no http error and business error. In this case, I want to return an empty instance to the subscriber. that's why I have this code : responseModel.data = T.Type()

but as you can see, there is a compile error, I don't know what's happening.

Appreciate for any suggestion:)

Comment: The compiler is getting confused because something else is wrong. One thing that caught my eye was `T.Type()`... What's that? Also, is `Localized` a function or a type? The upper-case implies type but the way it's used implies it's a function.

Comment: Localized() is clear.Its a function to do localization. The problem is not here.

Comment: I know that it's not the problem. I just found it odd that the function starts with an upper-case letter. That's not standard Swift style guidelines.

Comment: Yeah commonly we don't do like this.But I don't won't to define a lot of classes, I just want some functions.It's a Golang style function.Or you can say its an OC style definition.

Comment: In Swift, they are called "free functions". As in they are free of any container (class/struct/enum). And we still use lowercase for the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the offending line. You already established that sometimes the server can return nil so allow this function to return nil...

```
.map { result in
    print(String(data: result.data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "111")

    let responseModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseModel<T>.self, from: result.data)
    if responseModel.code != 0 { // business error
        let msg = (responseModel.msgCode != nil) ? Localized(key: "\(responseModel.msgCode!)") : responseModel.msg
        UIApplication.shared.currentKeyWindow()?.showHUD(msg)
        return nil
    }
    return responseModel.data
}
```

If you really want to be able to detect an error at the call sight, then have this function emit an error.

Comment: but there is a compile error. you can check the image.

Comment: I understand there is a compile error, but the compiler is confused as to what the real problem is. The real problem is in your `responseModel.data = T.Type()` line.